# Transfer data from onClick into $_POST

Tags: php, javascript

I call some links (opening table in the div) in the form

```
<A HREF="#1" onClick = ?????>button 1<A>
<A HREF="#2" onClick = ?????>button 2<A>
<A HREF="#3" onClick = ?????>button 3<A>
```

I would like through the onClick function to send data (numbers: 1, 2, 3) and receive it in PHP in the same document. I guess I have to commit to this form.
How to do it?

EDIT -------------------------------------

I try the @gilly3 way

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function submitValue (n) {     
var f = document.forms.myform_1;     
f.myNumber.value = n;     
f.submit(); 
} 
</script>

<?php
global $PHP_SELF;
echo "<form action='". htmlentities($PHP_SELF)."' method=\"POST\" id=\"myform_1\">";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="myNumber" /> 
<a href="#1" onclick="submitValue(1)">button 1</a> 
<a href="#2" onclick="submitValue(2)">button 2</a> 
<a href="#3" onclick="submitValue(3)">button 3</a>
</form>
```

tested - working ok. thnks for your help

Comment: Basically you want to tell the server which of those 3 links was clicked on?

Comment: Basically - yes yes yes :)) I have one long 7 scripts (one for every day of the week) at one php file. I think to reduce it to one script but I must inform php file about which day (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) we are tolking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add hidden fields to your form.  In your click handler, write whatever value you want to the hidden fields and call `form.submit()`.

```
function submitValue (n) {
    var f = document.forms.myForm;
    f.myNumber.value = n;
    f.submit();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myNumber" />
<a href="#1" onclick="submitValue(1)">button 1</a>
<a href="#2" onclick="submitValue(2)">button 2</a>
<a href="#3" onclick="submitValue(3)">button 3</a>
```

Or get the value from `$_GET` and skip the JavaScript:

```
<a href="?day=1">button 1</a>
<a href="?day=2">button 2</a>
<a href="?day=3">button 3</a>
```

Comment: I can't do this ?day=1 course #1 must be there. I have one problem with your solution

Comment: If you need `#1` then try `href="?day=1#1`.  The querystring must come before the hash.

Comment: #1 is using by the plugin Tabify blok, I think it will be not work via GET. Please, see at my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery

```
$('#anchorid').click(function(){
   $.post('self.php',{data:'1'},function(){
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thnks but how make it with 7 links?